# Pod install error within terminal

Tags: cocoapods, podfile

[Pod File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMjkW.png)  this error  [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `Pod' for # Did you mean?  pod. is occuring when I am trying to pod install. In my pod file i have just added 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'

This is a terminal error with cocoapods, also an error with the import the way i imported was

import SwiftKeychainWrapper

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `Pod' for #
Did you mean?  pod.

#
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  pod 'Firebase/Database'

> Pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'
>    #
>    #  -------------------------------------------

Comment: Show your pod file then...

Comment: Copy/paste code (or pod file), not screen shot. Also, copy/paste the full error, but please format it.

Comment: @Jogrammin You need to uncomment your pod target on the second line

Comment: what are comments indicated with inside of the podfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove capital **P**, pod must be write with **p** not with **P**.
Try this `pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'`

ps.

If you read carefully the error

> [!] Invalid Podfile file: undefined method `Pod' for # Did you mean?
>   pod.

it says that **Pod** does not exist. Did you mean **pod**